# Mongodb for Transactional based activities

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, transactions

Currently I am working on a financial application where complex transaction can be occurred. For this purpose, I have 2 options, either use Mongodb or Relational databases to store core transactional data.

So I have read different blogs, and found that Mongodb is schema-less(flexible) as well as faster than relational databases like MySQL, but unfortunately it doesn't give any transactional support(like Serializable Isolation level)!. It just give concurrency control/ atomicity on single document level. So what if a transaction requires to change multiple documents!
According to the documentation of MongoDB:

> "An isolated write operation does not provide “all-or-nothing”
>   atomicity. That is, an error during the write operation does not roll
>   back all its changes that preceded the error."

Even Mongodb have transactional support, but its too complex and not as flexible as that of relational db, 
[Perform Two Phase Commits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/)

So can anyone tell me is it good to use Mongodb for such operations or any Relational database?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB will support transactions soon: 
https://www.mongodb.com/transactions

So I guess if your application has critical operations that need transactions, use a relational DB.
Or you have to wait MongoDB version 4.0 to be released. Hopefully in the current year, this is already a beta and a release is actually planned for summer 2018...